# Kubernet local setup for development/testing

Tags: kubernetes

I need 6 Springboot Microservices, 1 PostgreSQL and 1 Angular application to run in Kubernet with minikube. This requirement is for development/testing. To setup this environment locally can I use Ubuntu Linux machine with 12 GB RAM and 500 HDD machine.
As a Kubernetes learner, you may think this question is silly, but please share your thoughts. I want to learn these technologies.

Comment: As I am not sure, I am commenting, but yes you can, and it is preferred to use an Ubuntu machine rather than a Windows machine. and the size or ram depends on how much your microservices and others will need. you can comment back if you have any other question I can help with.

Comment: The [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/) does include a couple of local environments that you can use for learning and experimentation, especially [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io) and [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io).  Do you have a more specific question or a technical problem you're running into?

Comment: Going in a different direction (and adding this as a comment since it's not a tool for single developers), [Signadot](https://www.signadot.com/) is a tool for teams to test on Kubernetes, its main concept is creating a forked version of a service under test.

Answer (score 0):

As George mentioned, you can use an Ubuntu machine rather than a Windows machine. And it totally depends upon the size or RAM on your microservices and other applications

As David Maze mentioned, kubernetes documentations include a couple of local environments which helps for your learning and experimentation.

You can refer to the [tutorial](https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-microservices-docker-and-kubernetes) written by Sravan Cynixit about the overview of building a few microservices using a spring boot, docker, and then deploy them into Kubernetes.

> **You need to plan a production environment to be able to deploy and test our sample microservices. You will realize that in the following
> steps:**
>
> - Initially you require one Kubernetes (Minikube)  node cluster instance running on your local computer.
> - Spring boot Cloud Kubernetes includes access to the Kubernetes API for a list of addresses to be obtained for pods running for a single
>   operation.

You can also refer to the [doc](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-minikube-for-local-kubernetes-development-and-testing) written by Alex Garnett for further information.